# Diff two files and print output of nth line above it too in unix

Tags: shell, unix, diff, aix

We have two files in which i want to diff and print that line and 4th line which is above that difference line. 
For example in this case , diff is between line having debug:ON/OFF and i want to print line with value "AR1LogHandler.properties" too.

FILE 1   ----

```
<configuration-file name="**AR1LogHandler.properties**">                                                                                     
<parameters>                                                                                                       
<parameter name-path="system.severity" 
value="fatal:yes;error:yes;information:yes;**warning:yes;debug:yes**" 
sticky="true" exists="true"/>                                                                                                
</parameters>                                                                                   
</configuration-file>
```

FILE 2 ---

```
<configuration-file name="**AR1LogHandler.properties**">                                                                                       
<parameters>                                                                                                        
<parameter name-path="system.severity" 
 value="fatal:yes;error:yes;information:yes;**warning:no;debug:no**" 
 sticky="true" exists="true"/>                                                                                                
</parameters>                                                                                        
</configuration-file>
```

Comment: Like `diff -uNb -B4 file1 file2`?  (or `-B3` if you are looking for the `...fatal...` line)

Comment: Please explain what you want. I think that you want the 3rd line above when the diff is found in the parameter name path. And what do you want when you have more <parameter> blocks inside the `<parameters>` block?  
Do you want the previous line with `configuration-file` above any difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hackish combination of `diff`, `tail` and `sed` to pick only the first line and the changed lines, e.g.

```
$ diff -uNb -B3 df1 df2 | tail -n +4 > tmp && \
  sed '0,/^[ ]/!d' tmp && \
  sed '/^[^-+]/d' tmp && rm tmp
 <configuration-file name="**AR1LogHandler.properties**">
-value="fatal:yes;error:yes;information:yes;**warning:yes;debug:yes**"
+value="fatal:yes;error:yes;information:yes;**warning:no;debug:no**"
```

Not pretty, but is preserves the 1st line showing the properties, and then what has changed in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry i didn't inform earlier  that i need to do in AIX machine. And Nb option will not work in AIX.